# extracting from list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries.
Keys in every dictionary in the list have another dictionary as a value.

```
[{'A':{'AX':'','source':'rock'}},
{'B':{'BX':'','source':'paper'}},
{'C':{'CX':'','source':'scissors'}}]
```

I would need to list out the values of the 'source' key in all the child dictionaries in the list (one-liner if possible)- as a set.
Expected output:

```
['rock','paper','scissors']
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dlist` is your list of dictionaries, then:

```
values = set([list(d.values())[0]['source'] for d in dlist])
```

Additionally, if you don't care about mutating the dictionaries, you can also do this:

```
values = set([d.popitem()[1]['source'] for d in dlist])
```

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve it via using *nested list comprehension expression* as:

```
my_list = [{'A':{'AX':'','source':'rock'}},
           {'B':{'BX':'','source':'paper'}},
           {'C':{'CX':'','source':'scissors'}}]

my_values = [v['source'] for l in my_list for v in l.values()]
```

where value hold by `my_values` will be:

```
['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
```

If you want to get unique elements (in case there is possibility of duplicate values), you have to type-cast `my_values` to `set` as:

```
set(my_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested iterations:

```
original_list = [{'A':{'AX':'','source':'rock'}},
                 {'B':{'BX':'','source':'paper'}},
                 {'C':{'CX':'','source':'scissors'}}]
output = []
for item in original_list:
    for k, v in item.iteritems():
        output.append(v['source'])
```